# Find the CDF of the perimeter of an isosceles triangle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

> The angle in an isosceles triangle is a continuous uniform distribution in $(0,\pi)$ and between the two sides with the same length. Find the CDF of the perimeter of such a triangle.

I'm new to probability theory so bear with me.

First I need to express the perimeter with angle $\lambda$ and non-base-side $a$.

Using law of cosine I get $P=2a+c=2a+\sqrt{2a^2-2a^2\cos(\lambda)}$. Since base $c\in (0, 2a)$, the perimeter is in $(2a,4a)$.

Therefore: $F_U(z)=\mathbb{P}(U\leq z)=\mathbb{P}(\lambda\leq \cos^{-1}(\frac{-2a^2+4az-z^2}{2a^2})/\pi)$

The $\pi$ in the denominator must be there because it's a uniform distribution.

All in all, I get... $F_U=\begin{cases} 0 \,& z \leq 2a\\ \cos^{-1}(\frac{-2a^2+4az-z^2}{2a^2})/\pi \,& 2a< z< 4a \\ 1 \, & z\geq4a\end{cases}$

Am I correct? What could I do better (especially in notation)?

Comment: Are you sure that your expression of $c$ is correct ? It should be $2a\sin(\lambda/2)$. Aside from that what you did seems correct.

Comment: @StratosFair yeah, I'm pretty sure the exp. for $c$ is correct. I'm using law of cosine $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\lambda)$. It seems like you're using sine law $\frac{c}{\sin(\lambda)}=\frac{a}{\sin((\pi-\lambda)/2)}$

Comment: The end point definitions should read $0$ for $z\le 2a$ and $1$ for $z\ge 4a$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg thanks!